# Represent white spots by rectangles

Tags: matlab, rectangles, region, drawrectangle

I have this binary image with white spots:
[image: Binary image]
I want to represent each white spot by a rectangle with the same size of spot and if possible with same orientation. There are any function that do that?
I can detect each spot using RP:
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would compute the smallest Feret diameter (shortest projection) with corresponding angle, and the perpendicular projection. That usually corresponds to the smallest bounding box.

See here for MATLAB code on computing Feret diameters: http://www.crisluengo.net/archives/408

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use `regionprops` as follows:

```
I = imread('tHZhy.png');
stats = regionprops(I, 'centroid', 'Orientation', 'MajorAxisLength','MinorAxisLength',  'BoundingBox');
figure
imshow(I)
hold on
for i=1:length(stats)
    xc = stats(i).Centroid;
    ma = stats(i).MajorAxisLength/2;
    mi = stats(i).MinorAxisLength/2;
    theta = -deg2rad(stats(i).Orientation);
    dx = [-ma -mi; ma -mi; ma mi; -ma mi; -ma -mi];
    R = [cos(theta) -sin(theta); sin(theta) cos(theta)]; % rotation matrix
    x = xc + dx*R';
    plot(xc(1), xc(2), 'g*');
    plot(x(:, 1), x(:, 2), 'g');
end
```

Note that the result is not perfect, especially for rather square objects. The reason therefore is that the major dimension is the greatest when it is directed along a diagonal.
[image]